# Wrong Coordinates in QGIS Map Grid

Tags: print-composer, wgs84

These are incorrect decimal degree coordinates for Puerto Rico. Layers are suppossed to be georeferenced or is this common for layer not georeferenced?

[image]

Comment: From where did you obtain the outline of the island, and what is the projection of the source file?